# a little bit confusing about a syntax on my databases MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

i try to check my databases with :

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| db1                |
| db2                |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0,09 sec)
```

I also try to check my databases on :

```
mysql> SELECT Db FROM mysql.db;
+--------------------+
| Db                 |
+--------------------+
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
| db1                |
| db2                |
| db1                |
| db2                |
+--------------------+
6 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

Why are the results different with `SHOW DATABASES;` and `SELECT Db FROM mysql.db;` ?

Can i update my databases on `mysql.db` tables ??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's best to keep away from system databases. If you want to find out about your dbs use information_schema.tables,Information_schema.columns etc

Comment: `mysql.db` is an internal table. Don't use it to make changes to your databases, because by updating this table you'll bypass some of the housework that MySQL does for you and risk corrupting your databases. Use `SHOW DATABASES`, `CREATE DATABASE` etc instead.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk P.Salmon why i have multiple of  `db1` databases on `mysql.db` tables?

Comment: If you dump all columns for the `db` table you'll see that MySQL stores different bits of info on your databases, which is why some of them may appear more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql.db id an internal system table, hence it is hard to find official documentation related to it. I found [this MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysqldb-table/), that states :

> mysql.db is a system table that contains information about database-level privileges

This table is about storing user’s `GRANTS` (which explains why you see the same db more than once).
Obviously it is not the good place to lookup available databases.

For that, it’s best to use [`SHOW DATABASES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html) or [the information schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can find database information by three methods:

1. The `mysql` database, which is an internal schema used by MySQL Server itself for its own bookkeeping.
2. The `SHOW` command, which is the earliest mechanism to expose the information to end users.
3. The `information_schema` database, which is a "virtual" database with dynamically generated tables, implemented later as an enhancement to `SHOW` commands.

You should be using any except the first one (mainly, because it doesn't contain what you think it does, but also because regular users should never have read access on it). In practice, I've found that whether to use `SHOW` or `information_schema` depends on the server: they some times have very different performance and you don't always have permissions for the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Fun fact: you can delete a database and still find its name on `mysql.db`. So that is one more point you cannot rely on.